# Android Fragments, ViewPager and device rotation, causes fragment orphans

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, xamarin.android

Like many others I have been fighting hard to understand androids fragments in combination with the view pager.

Here is setup: in portrait mode an activity has a xml layout that includes a viewpager that is bound to a FragmentStatePagerAdaper. This adapter does a good job constraining number of active fragments.

When the device is rotated the xml layout is very different with only one fragment and no viewpager. It works fine from a user perspective, but from the debugger and the fragment managers debug logging I can see that the last active fragments from the portrait layout is still alive and being resumed in the landscape mode as well. These fragments might perform some intensive data retrieval or other computation, and thus consume non significant resources and I want to get rid of them.

Then when device is rotated back to portrait mode I again can see that the fragment from landscape mode is still alive and being resumed.

The fragment in landscape mode is added to the fragment manager by code, and thus I can detect that it is hanging around in portrait mode and remove it from the fragmanager. But I have no clue of how to achieve the opposite i.e. remove orphan fragments managed by the view pager when being in landscape mode. I have seen some hacks that try to remove fragments by a known tag syntax, but the state adapter does not add fragments with a tag (as of the source: http://tinyurl.com/mdcuhk2) and I don't like this hacky idea.

I hope someone knows a ways around this.

Comment: Where do you initialise your `ViewPager`? Can you post some code?

Comment: The viewpager is from the xml layout and bound to the adapter in the OnCreate(..)'

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar kind of problem and I used this following code in AndroidManifest.xml under `<activity`

It may work with your code also:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"